# AutoLisp trying to move all polyline RECTANGLE to a specific point. Any thoughts?

Tags: lisp, autocad, autocad-plugin, autolisp

So I have this code :

```
    (setq ss (ssget "X" '((0 . "LWPOLYLINE") (90 . 4) (-4 . "&=") (70 . 1) )))
    ;Selecteaza toate Polyline-urile cu 4 colturi, si care sunt inchise.
    (setq n 0
          var (getpoint "Select where to order rentagles")
          )
    (repeat  (sslength ss) ;Parcurge setul de selectie
      (setq tent (entget (ssname ss n))
        telem (assoc 10 tent)
        listvar(cons 10 var))
      (setq
        tent(subst listvar telem tent)
        )
      (entmod tent)
      (setq n (1+ n))
      )
  (princ)
  )
```

Although what it does is that, it moves only the upper left corner of any rectangles to my specified point. How can I do the same for the WHOLE rectangle, or how can I change the other corners using dxf codes ? 
Thanks in advance!

EDIT : I've read this  " 10 Vertex coordinates (in OCS), multiple entries; one entry for each vertex
DXF: X value; APP: 2D point "
How Can I use the other entries of the vertexes?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to calculate the vector between the vertex that you wish to align and your target point, and then translate all vertices by the same vector.

For example ([using code from your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61620127/7531598)):

```
(defun c:moverect ( / a b c d e i p s v x )
    (cond
        (   (not (setq s (ssget "_X" '((0 . "LWPOLYLINE") (90 . 4) (-4 . "&=") (70 . 1)))))
            (princ "\nNo closed polylines found.")
        )
        (   (setq p (getpoint "\nSpecify target point: "))
            (setq p (trans p 1 (trans '(0 0 1) 1 0 t)))
            (repeat (setq i (sslength s))
                (setq i (1- i)
                      e (ssname s i)
                      x (entget e)
                )
                (mapcar 'set '(a b c d) (mapcar 'cdr (vl-remove-if-not '(lambda ( x ) (= 10 (car x))) x)))
                (if
                    (and
                        (equal (distance a b) (distance c d) 1e-8)
                        (equal (distance b c) (distance a d) 1e-8)
                        (equal (distance a c) (distance b d) 1e-8)
                    )
                    (progn
                        (setq v (mapcar '- p a))
                        (entmod
                            (mapcar
                               '(lambda ( x )
                                    (if (= 10 (car x))
                                        (cons 10 (mapcar '+ (cdr x) v))
                                        x
                                    )
                                )
                                x
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
    (princ)
)
```

However, note that the vertex aligned with the target point will be dependent on the direction of the 2D polyline - you may want to include a test to always choose, say, the lower-left vertex to align - and you'll then need to decide how to handle rotated rectangles.

Comment: Could you maybe give me an example with the code that I have in this example? I'm still a beginner and using those functons seems counter intuitive for me...